# is it possible to filterout Micorprofile @Counted metric based on PathParam?

Tags: eclipse, metrics, instrumentation, telemetry, microprofile

[Eclipse MicroProfile](https://github.com/eclipse/microprofile-metrics) defines a set of metrics (such as @Counted, @Timed, @Metered) which are useful for instrumentation and observability of a microservices.

My question is that if I have an endpoint like

```
@Counted(name = "greetingCount" )
@Path("hello/{name}")
@GET
public String greeting(@PathParam("name") String name) {
    return ("Hello "+ name);
}
```

can I modify @Counted metric in any way that it counts requests ,separately, based on Path Parameter so **hello/joe** would be counted separate from **hello/jill**
or at least provide a way to filter the count based on Path Parameter?
Alternatively, is there way to write a custom MP metric to achieve that?

Another question, can I count based on any characteristic of Response object (e.g. Http Status code of Response) ?